# Funcion JS solo se ejecuta una vez

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

mi problema es que mi función JS solo me funciona la primera vez que la ejecuto y si la intento ejecutar por segunda vez me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#btnActualizar').click(function(){
                actualizarHabitacion();
            });

        });

    </script>
```

---

```
function actualizarHabitacion(){

    id=$('#txtIdUp').val(); 
    tip=$('#editTipo').val();
    capadu=$('#editCapAdu').val();
    capnin=$('#editCapNin').val();
    capmax=$('#editCapMax').val();
    valadu=$('#editValAdu').val();
    valnin=$('#editValNin').val();
    des=$('#editDescripcion').val();

    actualizarHabitacion = "";
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/updates.php",
        data: {id,tip,capadu,capnin,capmax,valadu,valnin,des,actualizarHabitacion},
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla_habitaciones.php');
                alertify.success("Habitacion Actualizada con exito");
            }else{
                alertify.error("Fallo el servido");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

La unica forma de volver a ejecutarla es recargando la pagina, cosa que no quiero. Se agradecería si me pudieran dar algún consejo :)

Comment: podria usar algo asi tambien: const handler = function () {
  console.log("Tada!")
}
element.addEventListener("click", handler)
http://www.jstips.co/es_es/javascript/DOM-event-listening-made-easy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error no está en el envío de datos sino en la sobre escritura de la función `actualizarHabitacion`, dado que la función está definida en el ámbito global y no defines una variable `actualizarHabitacion` cuando haces esto `actualizarHabitacion = "";` le dices a tu programa que ahora la función `actualizarHabitacion` es un `string` y la segunda vez que llamas a la función ya no existe como función sino como string y `actualizarHabitacion()` no es válido.:

```
function actualizarHabitacion(){

    id=$('#txtIdUp').val(); 
    tip=$('#editTipo').val();
    capadu=$('#editCapAdu').val();
    capnin=$('#editCapNin').val();
    capmax=$('#editCapMax').val();
    valadu=$('#editValAdu').val();
    valnin=$('#editValNin').val();
    des=$('#editDescripcion').val();

    actualizarHabitacion = ""; <---------cambio en la definicion de la funcion
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/updates.php",
        data: {id,tip,capadu,capnin,capmax,valadu,valnin,des,actualizarHabitacion},
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla_habitaciones.php');
                alertify.success("Habitacion Actualizada con exito");
            }else{
                alertify.error("Fallo el servido");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado... el error lo ocasionaba los datos enviados por ajax, los metí todos en un cadena y el problema se arreglo:

```
function actualizarHabitacion(){

    id=$('#txtIdUp').val(); 
    tip=$('#editTipo').val();
    capadu=$('#editCapAdu').val();
    capnin=$('#editCapNin').val();
    capmax=$('#editCapMax').val();
    valadu=$('#editValAdu').val();
    valnin=$('#editValNin').val();
    des=$('#editDescripcion').val();

    cadena= "id=" + id +
            "&tip=" + tip +
            "&capadu=" + capadu + 
            "&capnin=" + capnin +
            "&capmax=" + capmax + 
            "&valadu=" + valadu + 
            "&valnin=" + valnin +
            "&des=" + des +
            "&actualizarHabitacion=" + "";

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/updates.php",
        data: cadena,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla_habitaciones.php');
                alertify.success("Habitacion Actualizada con exito");
            }else{
                alertify.error("Fallo el servido");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: El error no está en el envío de datos sino en la sobreescritura de la función actualizarHabitacion, dado que la función está definida en el ámbito global y no defines una variable actualizarHabitacion cuando haces esto actualizarHabitacion = ""; le dices a tu programa que ahora la función actualizarHabitacion es un string y la segunda vez que llamas a la función ya no existe como función sino como string y actualizarHabitacion() no es válido.